# How to do a triple Diffie-Hellman(3 - DH) key agreement in Java using bouncy castle?

Tags: bouncycastle, diffie-hellman, kdf, hkdf

There are ample examples on how to do Diffie-Hellman key agreement to compute a shared secret. However, I could not find any example on how to do 3DH in java using bouncy castle(or any security provided to be honest). All of what I am finding, reading is abstract theory, and not actual real implementation/example.

More specifically, how can the three individually computed DH agreements be combined?
A good source of reference could be [Signal's x3dh agreement protocol](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/#sending-the-initial-message) :

pseudo code

```
    DH1 = DH(IKA, SPKB)
    DH2 = DH(EKA, IKB)
    DH3 = DH(EKA, SPKB)
    SK = KDF(DH1 || DH2 || DH3)
```

or alternatively:

```
KeyAgreement ka1 = KeyAgreement.getInstance("X448",BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME); ka1.init(iPrivKey); //initator Private Key
ka1.doPhase(rPubKey, true); //recipient Public Key
byte[] secret1 = ka1.generateSecret();
... 

byte[] secret2 = ka2.generateSecret(); 
...

byte[] secret3 = ka3.generateSecret();
```

To be exactly precise on what I am looking for how to do `SK = KDF(DH1 || DH2 || DH3)` having already computed DH1 DH2 and DH3 in bouncy castle? I.E how to combine secret1, secret2 and secret3 as input keying material or seed for HKDFParameters?

Comment: What exactly is unclear? KDF is defined in chapter _2.2. Cryptographic notation_ of your link as HKDF algorithm. BouncyCastle supports [HKDF](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/HKDFBytesGenerator.html).

Comment: @Topaco the documentation shared by does not tell how I can combine three Diffie hellman key agreements.

KeyAgreement ka1 = KeyAgreement.getInstance("X448",BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
ka1.init(iPrivKey);
ka1.doPhase(rPubKey, true);
byte[] secret1 = ka1.generateSecret();
...
byte[] secret2 = ka2.generateSecret();
...
byte[] secret3 = ka3.generateSecret();

now how do I combine secret1, secret2 and secret3 as input keying material or seed for HKDFParameters?

Comment: You should post the code in the question and not in the comment, because it is hard to read in the comment. In [2.2 Cryptographic notation](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/#cryptographic-notation) is explained e.g. for the input keying material: `IKM = F || KM`, where `KM` is the value passed in `KDF`, so `KM = secret1 || secret2 || secret3` and `F` are 57 `0xFF` bytes (for X448) and `||` means the concatenation of the byte sequences. Also the HKDF parameters `salt` and `info` are explained there.

Comment: @Topaco you are absolutely right. My bad for not posting in the question.

Also many thanks for spelling it out to me that ```||``` is concatenation as per signal documentation. It was all about reading it patiently, and I glossed over it like a chimp :D . I will try this out in my application and then if works out, will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Topaco it is just plain concatenation of the three shared secrets. Java code follows:

```
     byte[] getAgreementBytes(PrivateKey privKey,PublicKey pubKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException {
        KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("X448", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
        ka.init(privKey);
        ka.doPhase(pubKey, true);
        byte[] secret = ka.generateSecret();
        privKey = null;//let gc do it's work
        return secret;
    }
...
...
...

        byte[] secretA = getAgreementBytes(iPrivKeyA,getRPubKeyB());
        byte[] secretB = getAgreementBytes(iPrivKeyB,getRPubKeyC());
        byte[] secretC = getAgreementBytes(iPrivKeyC,getRPubKeyA());

        byte[] secret = new byte[secretA.length + secretB.length + secretC.length];
        System.arraycopy(secretA,0,secret,0,secretA.length);
        System.arraycopy(secretB,0,secret,secretA.length,secretB.length);
        System.arraycopy(secretC,0,secret,secretA.length + secretB.length,secretC.length);

        return secret;
```

The signal doc also mentions using 57 0xFF bytes (for X448), which I am yet to make sense of. However, the above code works for me.